# Merged Array unordered

Tags: arrays

So I have an issue with this code, I have these input.txt files and basically when i enter them it needs to order the arrays numerically, but i keep getting a logical error and it miss sorts just one number. What should I do to fix this, or where am I getting the error? I checked my loops and everything and just can't figure it out. What should be in input3_1 and input3_2 txt files are before the java code. Thanks in advance for the advice.

input3_1.txt = 8 3 13 5 10

input3_2.txt = 9 6 11 12 4 7 2

```
public class MergedArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1, s2;

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter File 1 name");
        s1 = inp.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter File 2 name");
        s2 = inp.nextLine();

        try {
            int[] arr1 = new int[20];
            int[] arr2 = new int[20];

            int cnt = 0;
            int c;
            int countFirst = 0, countSecond = 0;

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(s1 + ".txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                arr1[countFirst] = scanner.nextInt();
                countFirst++;
            }

            scanner = new Scanner(new File(s2 + ".txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                arr2[countSecond] = scanner.nextInt();
                countSecond++;
            }

            int[] merged = new int[countFirst + countSecond];
            int flag1 = 0, flag2 = 0, indexMerge = 0;
            int indexSecond = 0, indexFirst = 0;

            int traverse1 = countFirst;
            int traverse2 = countSecond;

            int c2, d, swap;

            for (c2 = 0; c2 < (countFirst - 1); c2++) {
                for (d = 0; d < (countFirst - 1) - c2 - 1; d++) {
                    if (arr1[d] > arr1[d + 1]) {
                        swap = arr1[d];
                        arr1[d] = arr1[d + 1];
                        arr1[d + 1] = swap;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (c2 = 0; c2 < (countSecond - 1); c2++) {
                for (d = 0; d < (countSecond) - c2 - 1; d++) {
                    if (arr2[d] > arr2[d + 1]) {
                        swap = arr2[d];
                        arr2[d] = arr2[d + 1];
                        arr2[d + 1] = swap;
                    }
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                if (arr1[indexFirst] <= arr2[indexSecond]) {
                    merged[indexMerge] = arr1[indexFirst];
                    indexFirst++;
                    traverse1--;
                } else {
                    merged[indexMerge] = arr2[indexSecond];
                    indexSecond++;
                    traverse2--;

                }
                indexMerge++;
                if (traverse1 == 0) {
                    flag1 = 1;
                    break;
                } else if (traverse2 == 0) {
                    flag2 = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag1 == 1) {
                while (indexSecond < countSecond) {
                    merged[indexMerge] = arr2[indexSecond];
                    indexMerge++;
                    indexSecond++;
                }
            } else {
                while (indexFirst < countFirst) {
                    merged[indexMerge] = arr1[indexFirst];
                    indexMerge++;
                    indexFirst++;
                }
            }

            int count = 0;

            while (count < (countFirst + countSecond)) {
                System.out.println(merged[count]);
                count++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: `where am I getting the error?` ... We don't know either because you never posted a stack trace nor did you tell us what happened when you ran the debugger.

Comment: what is a stack trace? I am new to this forum @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Are there any errors, or does the code simply run and complete normally?

Comment: It compiles and runs completely. But when I use the input txt files it doesn't sort them correctly. It puts 10 at the very bottom instead of after 9 and before 11

Comment: Someone is likely going to have to test your code.  Have you used a debugger yet?

Comment: I don't typically use a debugger so I am not sure how to use one.